# Android RadioButton logic

Tags: java, android, radio-button

How can I make a grouping of `RadioButton`, of which at most one can be checked, but which allows all buttons to be unchecked?  (I maintain that this has always been one of two common behaviours for groups of radio buttons.)

I haven't managed to get this to work with `RadioGroup`.  It allows all the buttons to be unchecked on creation, but once one button is checked, there seems no way to get back to the original all-unchecked state.  (Sure, in a parent's `onRadioButtonClicked()`, all the buttons can be unchecked -- but unfortunately by the time this is called, an unchecked button will already have been checked.  So I think it would be necessary to keep a separate accounting of which buttons were previously checked, in order to use that.)

Two options have occurred to me.

One is to make my own "ReasonableRadioGroup", that allows both common behaviors.  Seems a little extreme.

Another is to arrange for a long-click event on a checked button to uncheck the button -- but I don't think that would be obvious to a user.

But surely I'm just missing something!

Comment: You want to prevents RadioButtins to be checked? or do you want to clear when one of them is checked? or something else. the question is unclear.

Comment: I explained what should happen. My question is how to implement it.  This should be bloody easy.

Comment: Another option hadn't occurred to me, because it is sub-optimal.  That is, to add a button to each group "none of the above".  If there are several pairs of options that are mutually exclusive -- this adds 50% to the real estate, and screen clutter.  But it is easy to implement.  I'll see if I can get away with it on small screens.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make a grouping of RadioButton, of which at most one can be checked, but which allows all buttons to be unchecked?

Sorry, there is no support for that in the `RadioButton`/`RadioGroup` classes in the Android SDK. It is possible that [one of these libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/82?sort=created) offers that, though it does not look promising.

> But surely I'm just missing something!

No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
radioGroup.clearCheck();
```

Comment: Yes, as I said.  But where/when should I call that?  The problem is, without building some stuff to remember the previous button state, I don't know if the button was previously pressed or not.